# Putting unlabelled balls into labeled boxes

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to put $50$ unlabeled balls into $100$ labeled boxes? If empty boxes are allowed and you're also allowed to put as many balls as you want into a single box, would the answer be $\displaystyle\binom{149}{50}$?

Comment: Let $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{100}$ be the number of balls in each box.  It would be the number of non-negative integral solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{100}=50$.  What made you pick $149$?  What made you pick $100$?

Comment: I actually did originally write 50. The 149 came from the formula $(n-1 + k) choose k$

Comment: You use `/k`.  Remember the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$ is *very different* than $\frac{n}{r}$ and should not be confused.

Answer (score 2):

Let the balls be in line. Like this
$$ \circ \circ\circ\circ\circ\circ \dots \circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ $$
Then you divide them using $99$ barriers. Like this
$$ \circ \circ\circ\mid\mid  \circ\  \circ\mid\circ \dots \circ\circ\mid\circ\circ\circ \mid \circ \mid \mid $$
The spaces between the barriers and the extreme left and extreme right spaces can be considered as (labelled, as they are ordered) boxes. Now, this becomes a *permutation with repetition* problem: you have $149$ elements, $50$ equal balls and $99$ equal barriers. So the answer is $$\dfrac{149!}{50!\cdot99!} = \binom{149}{50}$$